# ClassNotFound Maven War

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, swagger, war

I'm building a multi-module Maven web app project, but I'm having trouble deploying the WAR on my Tomcat server.

My project structure is

- MyApp

  - MyAppSchemas
  - MyAppUtils
  - MyAppWs

Here's the problem.  When I try to deploy my generated war on my local Tomcat server, I get the following error:

```
Apr 19, 2017 1:42:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter ApiOriginFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.swagger.api.ApiOriginFilter
```

APIOriginFilter is a class generated  in the MyAppSchemas module.  I've included the MyAppSchemas jar as a dependency in the MyAppWs pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>MyAppWs</artifactId>
    <name>MyAppWs</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build> 
        <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>               
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>APP-INF/lib</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyAppSchemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyAppUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Bottom line: how do I include other submodules on my war runtime classpath?

Comment: I'm not convinced it will make a difference but remove the `maven-war-plugin` configuration. It's complete nonsense in a Tomcat context. Then after executing a `mvn clean install` verify that your dependent jars have been placed in the `MyAppWs/target/MyAppWs/WEB-INF/lib` directory which is generated during the process of building your WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding your classes to an external jar and marking it as a dependency.

Add the dependency via a System scope

```
<dependency>
   ..
   <scope>system<scope>
   <systemPath>your jar path</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Then define using the plugin as below

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>directory path/*.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but shouldn't there be a way to do with this just maven submodule dependencies?

Comment: Normally this style is followed as it is flexible when we need to reference custom classes.